# Clean url disabling not working

Tags: caching, uri

For some reason Drupal is parsing my landing pages address with both alias and clean url. Meaning that the landing page for new users becomes /dashboard&destination=node/30 instead of ?q=dashboard or ?q=node/30.

I have tried disabling clean url by unchecking use clean urls (?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls) and clearing the cache, but it still uses them (e.g problem continues). So I was hoping somebody might enlighten me how to force Drupal not to use clean url:s?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run drush command : ***`drush vset clean_url 0 --yes`***

or

Include a line in settings.php : ***`$conf['clean_url'] = 0;`***

**Updated :**

Check this [LINK](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9176/how-do-i-reset-the-clean-urls). There are many ways to disable the clean url.

Comment: Added the line to settings.php but it still keeps parsing the url in the same way

Comment: check the updated answer @newbie

Comment: I am accepting yous answer, since upon diving deeper to the problem it would seem that the real issue is with Drupal login and its redirection (it somehow still gets the clean url values, but is not neccecearly a clean url problem)